# How can I show my dist folder but not node_modules?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I want to be able to see my `dist` folder but not `node_modules`.

In `Settings > Directories`, the `Excluded` button is locked so I cannot set the `dist` folder as unmarked. What can I do to include this folder?

[image]

Comment: Interesting, there seems to be a bug somewhere. Right-clicking the folder (on the Project View) and clicking `Mark Directory As > Cancel Exclusion` then doing it again and clicking `Mark Directory As > Not Excluded` seems to do it, which is weird already (seems like the same action twice?) but that settings page is still showing it as excluded (only on the left pane), and seems generally buggy when it comes to that folder. It's probably ignored by default in node projects, but I have no idea where it's coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use webpack in your project? WebStorm auto-excludes webpack destination folder from indexing for better performance. So, if you have smth. like

```
output   : {
    path         : path.join(__dirname, 'dist/')
```

In your `webpack.config.js`, the `dist` folder will be auto-excluded.

As a workaround, try setting webpack configuration path value (**Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack**) to empty string - it should help.

Un-excluding the folder manually by choosing **Mark Directory As > Cancel Exclusion** in the **Project** tool window might also work